# Is there a API to create sites an Azure App Service dynamically from a web app

Tags: visual-studio, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

My requirement is to develop an application that should

1. create static html files
2. create a new site (with the static html files in #1) in Azure App Service or Hosting server.

i.e for #2,I need to automate the Publish activity that's done from Visual Studio to take it to the public server. So say on a Button click, the app should use the required details like credentials, app service\hosting provider details... and create a new site there.

**My Query**

Is this possible?

If so please do share it with me or send me some pointers on it.

Else let me know how I can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create azure app service using rest api with this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdate).

Also, you could deploy webapp to azure app service with ZIP or WAR file. Please refer to this [one](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip-deployment).

The required details like credentials, app service\hosting provider details you need to manually fill down to achieve deploy webapp function.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this would suit my case. I shall try it and get back to you. But Is there be any additional cost related to the number of increasing sites(SPAs) that gets added up to the app service?

Comment: The cost is depend  on your app service plan instead of the number of sites.